# How to query collection of objects while grouping by a property

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

So I am trying to write a query that will select a collection of objects that are distinct on a certain property.

Action:

```
+-----+-----------+-----+
| id  | timestamp | ... |
+-----+-----------+-----+
|  10 | 16:04     | ... |
|  11 | 16:06     | ... |
|  12 | 16:08     | ... |
|  13 | 16:09     | ... |
|  14 | 16:10     | ... |
+-----+-----------+-----+
```

FooVersion:

```
+----+--------+-----------+-------------------+
| id | foo_id | action_id | foo_zab           |
+----+--------+-----------+-------------------+
|  1 |      1 |        10 | xx                |
|  2 |      2 |        11 | yy                |
|  3 |      3 |        12 | zz                |
|  4 |      3 |        13 | zy                |
|  5 |      3 |        14 | zx                |
+----+--------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Foo:

```
+----+-----+
| id | zab |
+----+-----+
|  1 | xx  |
|  2 | yy  |
|  3 | zx  |
+----+-----+
```

A scene is made up of a collection of foos. I am trying to track the changes in each particular foo over time. Therefore, each time a change is made to foo, the action that caused that change is recorded and a copy of some of foo's properties are stored in the `foo_versions` table

What I am looking for is the "state of the foos at a particular action". So, while action #11 only specifically links to foo, the state of the scene at action #11 actually contains 3 foos, the versions of which are foo_version #1, #2, and #5

I need to construct a query that will say "for a specified action, give me the representation of the scene"

For action #10, the scene would be `[<foo_version #1>]`

For action #12, the scene would be `[<foo_version #1>, <foo_version #2>, <foo_version #3>]`

This is where it gets tricky. For action #14, the representation of the scene is `[<foo_version #1>, <foo_version #2>, <foo_version #5>]`. Foo versions #3, #4, and #5 all refer to the same foo. So, foo versions #3 and #4 are overwritten by #5.

I am using this sqlalchemy query:

```
stmt = db.session.query(Action).filter(Action.timestamp <= action.timestamp).subquery()
action_alias = aliased(Action, stmt)

foo_versions = db.session.query(FooVersion) \
                         .join(Action) \
                         .join(action_alias, FooVersion.action) \
                         .filter(Action.frame_id == frame.id) \
                         .all()
```

The result I am getting is

```
[<foo_version #1>, <foo_version #2>, <foo_version #3>, <foo_version #4>, <foo_version #5>]]]
                                     |____________|    |____________|
                                           ^                 ^
                                           |                 |
I need to get rid of these versions     -> |                 |
since they have been overwritten
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with python but here is the SQL query if I got correctly what you want:

```
SELECT a.id as action_id, timestamp, 
v.id as version, foo_id, foo_zab
FROM action a
JOIN foo_version v 
ON ( v.action_id IN
  ( 
    SELECT MAX(inner_v.action_id)
    FROM foo_version inner_v 
    WHERE a.id >= inner_v.action_id
    GROUP BY inner_v.foo_id
  )                      
)
JOIN foo ON ( foo.id = v.foo_id ) 
ORDER BY a.id, version
```

It will give you each action row repeated with the data of each version 
and here is a [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f8bc9/19)